# Wordpress session variable not working

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have an issue with a WordPress session. I have a file 'test.php' that is used post a variable to a WordPress site. It has the condition: "if the session variable is set then the user can access the whole WordPress site, and if the session variable is not set then user can't access the site".

When I post the variable to the WordPress site using test.php the homepage works fine, but when I access inner pages like 'xyz.com/contact' I get an error `Not Access` which means that the session variable was cleared on the next page.

Here is the test.php file:

```
<form action="wordpress-site-link" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="var" value="go"/>
</form>
```

In the file themes/theme-name/header.php I wrote this code:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['var'])) {
      echo 'Welcome'; 
}  else if(isset($_POST['var'])) {
       $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['var']; 
} else {
       echo 'No access...';
       exit; 
}
```

Comment: don't assume the session started. Wordpuke may already have output other stuff, causing "headers already sent" errors. Check the return value of `session_start()` - it's boolean false on failure.

Comment: Check if the remaining pages are different than the homepage, for example, the homepage starts with www. and the remaining pages do not. In this case, the session is only set for the homepage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just hook a function on "init" in your functions.php like this :

```
function ur_theme_start_session()
{
    if (!session_id())
        session_start();
}
add_action("init", "ur_theme_start_session", 1);
```

Then u can use your session variables.

I hope that help u.

Comment: Did you remove `session_start()` in your file header.php ?

Comment: If you must use native sessions for some reason (there are other ways https://pressjitsu.com/blog/wordpress-sessions-performance/ ) you should consider closing the session right after you're done with it - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php