# Using $_SESSION or $_COOKIE that were set in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

I am trying to know how people get to my site so links will have a query string "kw" to identify them. Incoming links look like:

> mysite.com?kw=ABC
>
> mysite.com/PAGE?kw=XYZ
>
> mysite.com/blog/post?kw=123

The problem for me has always been that I can't get `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` that were set in wordpress. So users who come in to mysite.com/blog/ (where I have wordpress), I set this:

```
if ((isset($_GET['kw']))||(!isset($_COOKIE['kw']))) {
    setcookie('kw',$_GET['kw'], time()+3600*24, '/',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],false);   
    $_SESSION['kw']=$_GET['kw'];
}
```

So it should set both the `$_SESSION['kw']` and `$_COOKIE['kw']`. If I go to another page on my site though, the `$_COOKIE` remains unset and the `$_SESSION` starts over. I put `session_start();` in my `wp-config.php`.

Does wordpress do something to these to keep them from being shared with the rest of my site?

EDIT - I've noticed that after I load a URL like mysite.com/blog/post?kw=123 where "123" is not being stored, if I then put my cursor in the address bar and hit return, it will be stored and I can access it outside. If I reload the page, it won't though. What's up with that?

Comment: Are you sure that session_start called properly or you are not modifying somehow session_id ? because $_SESSION should not be dropped over whole website.

Answer (score 0):

U can use session, just need to add a function in your functions.php locate in the template directory.

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977806/wordpress-session-variable-not-working/32977997#32977997)

```
function ur_theme_start_session()
{
    if (!session_id())
        session_start();
}
add_action("init", "ur_theme_start_session", 1);
```

Comment: in template directory do you mean /wp-includes or do you mean the theme's functions.php?

Comment: Theme's functions.php