# Custom PHP Page within WordPress with $_SESSION

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a separate file , a custom php file that calls API from another system. I put it in a folder under the theme. 
Example, under wp-content/themes/myTheme/api

In the API , I have session_start and register a session  $_SESSION['data'] = "abc";
In the file itself the session is there, but once I go to another page within the theme, the session is gone.
In my theme header.php, there is session_start(). I am able to pass session from the files within the theme folder, but under the "api" folder I can't pass the session. Any idea how I should go about?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `$_SESSION['data']` probably, unless `data` is a defined constant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress session variable not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977806/wordpress-session-variable-not-working)

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks for pointing it out, it's $_SESSION['data']

Comment: @Nozifel Thanks, I tried the solution given but it's not working for me. 
It could be because my file is in a sub folder. 
Then I copy out the file to be in same directory as my other template files, which means under the same dir as theme files. 
it doesn't work too.

Comment: Did you remove the other "start_session" in your files ?

Comment: I need to know how works your api. Can't help more without it. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nozifel ,appreciate it!