# Get custom Session value on another page in wordpress template

Tags: php, session, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to make SESSION in WordPress and use my session value on another custom WordPress template.
For Example:I'm trying to transfer value `"$_SESSION['post_data']= $_POST['payvalue'];"` from one page to another on Wordpress template but can't get it working. After submitting from First page to Second page Session array on the second page appears to be empty.
On Second Page I print `"<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>"` but it returns empty array.

I've already inserted `session_start()` at all page.

How can I use my custom session value on the second page in Wordpress template?

Comment: Are those Wordpress Instances running on the same host?

Comment: @MiSAKACHi, Yes it's running on the same host

Comment: See this one... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32977997/6294600

Comment: @MiSAKACHi, It is working only once but after that it will give blank value.